# How to make TypeScript understand import paths for RequireJS plugins like "plugin!./path/to/foo"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

For example, suppose we write

```
import template from 'hb!./foo.hb'
```

How do we make TypeScript understand that (or to ignore it, because RequireJS will handle that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an ambient module declaration will let TypeScript know about the module, and prevent the compiler error.

From the TypeScript documentation regarding [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html):

> > The compiler will try to locate a file that represents the imported module. To do so the compiler follows one of two different strategies: Classic or Node.
> >
> > If that didn’t work and if the module name is non-relative, then the compiler will attempt to locate an ambient module declaration.

In your case you can add an ambient module definition:

```
//foo.d.ts
declare module "hb!./foo.hb" {
    export default class template { }
}
```

Then you could compile like:

```
tsc --module amd .\test.ts .\foo.d.ts
```

And get this output:

```
define(["require", "exports", "hb!./foo.hb"], function (require, exports, foo_hb_1) {
    "use strict";
    console.log(foo_hb_1["default"]);
});
```

What's important here is that the ambient module declaration is just telling TypeScript about what sort of thing `template` will be. As you can see from the compiled output, your module loader will actually be responsible for the real work.

**Update**

It is possible to use [wildcards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations) in module declarations. So you can declare a module like:

```
declare module "hb!*" {
    export default class template { }
}
```

Now you can import anything that matches `hb!*`:

```
import template from 'hb!./foo.hb'
import template from 'hb!./bar.hb'
import template from 'hb!./baz.hb'
```

Comment: Hmm, I suppose I would need to use `export =` format, since I need the export of the RequireJS plugin, which is an AMD module.

Comment: But, what if the app has hundreds of dependencies similar to `hb!blah.hb`. I wouldn't want to hard code the module name for each possible module. Is there a way to make it generic? Based on your idea, can I place a `.d.ts` file next to each one, then have `tsc` somehow know to look next to modules of that generic format?

Comment: Well, you can use a `tsconfig.json` file to tell the compiler where to look for all your files. That way it will automatically detect your `d.ts` files and include them. You might be able to write something that automatically generates the `d.ts` files too.

Comment: The documentation for the config file is here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: @trusktr Actually, you can make it generic. I've updated the answer to show how.